# How can i create Master detail page in asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can i display data in views in asp.net core MVC?.

I have the following json format data

```
[
    {
      "ProductID": "100000",
      "ProductName": "Product 1"
    },
    {
      "ProductID": "100001",
      "ProductName": "Product 2"
    },
    {
      "ProductID": "100002",
      "ProductName": "Product 3"
    },
    {
      "ProductID": "100002",
      "ProductName": "Product 4"
    }
]
```

I have this code to read the above json data,to read product information from the the above json data

```
public class GetProducts_Action : BaseEFAction<GetProducts_Action_Request, GetProducts_Action_Response>
    {
        public IFileProvider FileProvider { get; }

        public GetProducts_Action(ILogger<GetProducts_Action> logger, DBContext context, ITransactionManager scope, IFileProvider fileProvider) : base(logger, context, scope)
        {
            FileProvider = fileProvider;
        }

        protected override Task<GetProducts_Action_Response> PerformActionAsync(GetProducts_Action_Request request)
        {
            IList<ProductDTO> product;

            using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenText(FileProvider.GetFileInfo("Product.json").PhysicalPath))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                product = (IList<ProductDTO>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(IList<ProductDTO>));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(new GetProducts_Action_Response { Products = product });
        }
    }

    public class GetProducts_Action_Request : BaseActionRequest
    {

    }

    public class GetProducts_Action_Response : BaseActionResponse
    {
        public IList<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IProductService { Task<IList<ProductDTO>> GetProduct(); }
```

Controller Actions to display all products which works great

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts()
{
    var products = await ProductsService.GetProducts();
    return Json(products);
}
```

I am able to display all products using the above code and works perfect, i also created a link to the detail page and URL looks like this `localhost:3000/Product/Products/102`.But how can get product information by id and display in the detail page?.

I tried this

```
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsDetail(int id)
{
    var product = (await ProductsService.GetProducts()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductCode == id);
    if (product != null) {
        return Json(product);
    } else {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

but i get

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   'System.Collections.IList'

ProductList Structure

```
 public class ProductList
    {
       public string ProductCode { get; set; }
       public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have Grid in the detail View as

```
 @model ProductList

                                <div class="row">
                                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductList>()
                               .Name("grid")
                                .Columns(cols =>
                                {
                                      cols.Bound(ProductList => ProductList.ProductCode).Hidden(false).Title(Localizer["Column 1"].Value);
                                      cols.Bound(ProductList => ProductList.ProductName).Hidden(false).Title(Localizer["Column 2"].Value);
                                 })
                                //.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName(""))
                                .Excel(excel => excel
                                .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx")
                                .Filterable(true)
                                .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Grid"))
                                )
                                .Navigatable(true)
                                .Filterable(f => f.Enabled(true).Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
                                .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))
                                .Sortable()
                                .PersistSelection()
                                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                .ButtonCount(5)
                                .Refresh(true)
                                .PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 20 }))
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                             .Custom()
                                             .PageSize(10)
                                             .Transport(transport => transport
                                             .Read(read => read.Action("GetProductsDetail", "Product"))

                                             ))
                                )

                            </div>
```

Comment: How your view code look like ?

Comment: @TonyNgo i just want to display just product Name it doesnt matter how. currently i used kendo grid to read from` .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                 .Custom()
                                                 .PageSize(10)
                                                 .Transport(transport => transport
                                                 .Read(read => read.Action("GetProductsDetail", "Product"))` but that is not what im looking i just want to display product Name of the selected record

Comment: I cant help you if I dont know how your view look like

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown in the Controller or the View?

Comment: @TonyNgo i added at the bottom i tried to display the information in Kendo Grid but i doesn't have to be kendo i was testing using kendoGrid

Comment: Give us your `ProductList` structure, please.

Comment: looks like your missing `ToList()` at the end of `(await ProductsService.GetProducts()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductCode == id);`

Comment: @Phong added productList structure

Comment: Could you please get result from this one `var listOfproducts = (await ProductsService.GetProducts().ToList())`, After that, you can get value `var product = listOfproducts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductCode == id);`. Give me your feed back: result or error you are getting

Comment: @Phong it work but how can I pass Id to the controller and display fields in the detail page? for example when i click on id in the index to display product name and other detail about the product in the detail page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly,** You can get the result from this one

```
var listOfproducts = (await ProductsService.GetProducts().ToList());
```

After that, you can get value

```
var product = listOfproducts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductCode == id);
```

**Secondly,** As I can see, `GetProductsDetail` is returning `Json` so you are getting by Ajax. If you want to redirect into a page:

1. In Index view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("You_Controller_Name", "GetProductsDetail", new { id = item.ID }) |
```

2. You should return `return View(product);` instead of `Json`.

Read the following post to have a better understanding

[Get Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-controller-and-views)

[Passing Data from the Controller to the View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view#passing-data-from-the-controller-to-the-view)

Comment: It's done here `id = "#= ProductCode #" }`. In Controller You should return `View` instead of `Json`

Comment: To keep the simple question, You can create a new question then give me the post. I'll answer for you.

Comment: ok i posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181286/how-can-i-display-data-in-a-view