# How can i display data in a View

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

How can i display data in views in asp.net core MVC?. In the Index.cshtml I have the following link to the detail page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("You_Controller_Name", "GetProductsDetail", new { id = item.ID }) |
```

I have this controller to get product by ID

```
public IActionResult Detail()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpGet()]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsDetail(string id)
{
  var product_list = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();
  var product = product_list.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductCode == id);
  return view(product);
}
```

Need help on displaying Product information in the detail page.

Comment: Give us your `GetProductsDetail` View, please.

Comment: @Phong i just want to display a product name only. i have a Detail view i dont have  GetProductsDetail view, i want to display productName in Detail view. in a detail page i have kendo grid but i dont to display data using that

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in `GetProductsDetail` Action

```
return View("Detail", product);
```

Read the following to have a better understanding

**Updated**

You can store like this in

```
@ViewBag.ProductName = product.ProductName
```

In View:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.ProductName</h1>
```

**Full code**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsDetail(string id)
{
   var product_list = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();
   var product = product_list.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductCode == id);
   @ViewBag.ProductName = product.ProductName

   return View("Detail", product); // Make sure that in View is expecting `ProductList`, Otherwise, You just return View("Detail");

}
```

[Calling another different view from the controller using ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910530/calling-another-different-view-from-the-controller-using-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Thank you Phong but what is miss is displaying a field lets say inside <h1> tag

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Robert

Comment: Any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235640/how-can-i-display-sales-made-by-customer-in-customers-detail-page

Comment: I’m researching how to get how to get data from dB views

Comment: In this scope of the question, I think it's been done. Let's get started with a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass the `ProductName` to `Detail` action using `RedirectToAction`,and then display it on view using `ViewBag`.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsDetail(string id)
    {
       var product_list = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();
       var product = product_list.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductCode == id);
       return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { name = product.ProductName });

    }


public IActionResult Detail(string name)
    {
        ViewBag.ProductName = name;
        return View();
    }
```

Detail View:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.ProductName</h1>
```