# How can i display Sales made by customer in customers detail page

Tags: asp.net

How can i display data from Multiple Model. I have customer and Sale Table, when View detail slected i want to see the sales made by the selected Customer.

Customer Model

```
namespace MasterDetailMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Sales = new HashSet<Sale>();
        }

        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }


       public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

Sale Model

```
namespace MasterDetailMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Sale
    {
        public int SalesID { get; set; }
        public int SalesPersonID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Customer Controller

```
namespace MasterDetailMVC.Controllers
{
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
private salesdbEntities db = new salesdbEntities();
// GET: Customers
public ActionResult Index()
{
 return View(db.Customers.ToList());
 }
 // GET: Customers/Details/5
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
 {
 Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
  if (customer == null)
  {
  return HttpNotFound();
 }
  return View(customer);
 }
 }
```

Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<MasterDetailMVC.Models.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleInitial)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleInitial)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CustomerID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CustomerID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CustomerID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Detail View

```
@model MasterDetailMVC.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Customer</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleInitial)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MiddleInitial)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.CustomerID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

when i go this link `Customers/Details/5` I want to display sales mad by this customer in a Table or grid.

sales Table looks like this

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [SalesID]
      ,[SalesPersonID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[Quantity]
  FROM [salesdb].[dbo].[Sales]
```

Product Table looks Like this

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Price]
  FROM [salesdb].[dbo].[Products]
```

Sales Person/Employee Table

```
 SELECT TOP (1000) [EmployeeID]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[MiddleInitial]
      ,[LastName]
  FROM [salesdb].[dbo].[Employees]
```

Comment: What does the view look like?

Comment: added Customer View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

You need to create `CustomerViewModel`

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<SaleViewModel> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

and `SaleViewModel` like below

```
public class SaleViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

You can get a list of view `SaleViewModel` by joining between `Sales` and `Products` table like below

```
var sales = (from s in db.Sales
                join p in db.Products on s.ProductId equals p.ProductID
                where s.CustomerID == id
                select new SaleViewModel 
                {
                    ProductId = s.ProductId,
                    ProductName = p.ProductName,
                    Price = p.Price
                    Quantity = s.Quantity
                }).ToList();
var result = new CustomerViewModel 
{
  CustomerID = customer.CustomerID, 
  FirstName = customer.FirstName,
  MiddleInitial = customer.MiddleInitial,
  LastName = customer.LastName,
  Sales = sales
}
```

**View**

```
@model MasterDetailMVC.Models.CustomerViewModel

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "List of item by Customer";
}
<table>
    <th>
      <td>Product Name </td>
      // The rest of items....
    </th>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Sales)
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ProductName</td>
            // The rest of items....
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Is that a new controller or updating Detail Controller

Comment: Wait, in Detail view is expecting `@model MasterDetailMVC.Models.Customer`

Comment: In this line `  where s.CustomerID = id` i get `can not convert int to bool"

Comment: It should be `s.CustomerID == id`. Anyway, I've just updated my answer, please take a look at

Comment: Ok can you check this Phong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348462/how-can-i-get-data-from-related-table-entity

Comment: @pong if you familiar with Kendo can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687462/how-can-i-create-kendo-tree-view